# Elasticsearch sort search results without term

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I want to retrieve all records inside a particular type and sort it using a date field. I am using this code:

```
{
   "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "type" : { 
                    "value" : "articles" 
                }
            }
         }
     },
    "from":0,
    "size":10,
    "sort":[
         {
            "date_entered":{
                "order":"desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But, the output from this query seems to be not sorted with the specified field. The field date_entered is formatted like this: *January 01, 1970 12:00 AM*

How can I return all the records within a page that is sorted using the date_entered field?

Comment: how is the `date_entered` field defined, e.g. in your mapping did you specify it as a date field?

Comment: no, I am using the PHP API for elasticsearch, and I don't know how to specify data type

Comment: To get the mapping see http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/indices-get-mapping.html